# Create new column using df.apply on list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to programming with Python, and I have a problem that I hope some of you can help me with.
I am working on a json file with a lot of different data which I have made into a dataframe. In the json file there are 27 keys, where one of them is named ratings. Under the ratings key there are multiple different lists including a list of strings named "review". I need to get the review list out as a new column in the dataframe so I can run som analysis on it. I have tried the following things:

```
df['review'] = df.ratings.apply(lambda x: x['review'])

df['review'] = df.ratings.apply(lambda row: (row['review'])

df['review'] = df['ratings'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('#\d+', '', x['review']))
```

All of which do not work. So do some of you where the mistake is, or know a better way for me to do this?

Thank you so much for your help and time :)
Sample of the json file

```
{"ratings": [{"date": "2018-09-04", 
"name": "MK", 
"url": "", 
"title": "employee", 
"photo": ".jpg", "team": 5, 
"vision": 5, 
"product": 5, 
"profile": 0, 
"review": "The team is building the product with full force and constantly updates the community, if the team can acquire more users it will be a superb blockchain-based product", 
"weight": "22%", 
"agree": 0}]}
```

Comment: add a sample of the JSON to your question.  I would expect use of `pd.json_normalize()` or `apply(pd.Series)` will do what you need

Comment: Hi, I have added a little bit of the code in a picture now :) and great I will try that

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not add code or data as links or pictures, it is hard for people who want to help you to copy it. Instead, write it directly into your post and format it as code.

Comment: Hi thank you for pointing that out, I have corrected it now :) I hope it is better now :)

Comment: ratings needs to be closed. Missing `]`

Answer (score 0):

- amended your sample JSON to make it valid and to demonstrate approach
- simple use of `explode()` of **list**
- `apply(pd.Series)` to expand embedded **dict**

```
js = {"movie":"best movie", "ratings": [{"date": "2017-09-29", "name": "Gerard Paul S. Netro",
"url": "gerard-paul-s-netro", 
"title": "Blockchain Entrepreneur &amp; ICO Expert", 
"photo": "https://icobench.com/images/users/gerard-paul-s-netro-1506943906.jpg", 
"team": 4, "vision": 5, "product": 5, "profile": 0, 
"review": "", "weight": "3%", "agree": 0}]}

df = pd.json_normalize(js)
# explode the list
df = df.explode("ratings")
# expand embedded dict
df.join(df.ratings.apply(pd.Series))
```

#### output

|  | movie | ratings | date | name | url | title | photo | team | vision | product | profile | review | weight | agree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | best movie | {'date': '2017-09-29', 'name': 'Gerard Paul S. Netro', 'url': 'gerard-paul-s-netro', 'title': 'Blockchain Entrepreneur & ICO Expert', 'photo': 'https://icobench.com/images/users/gerard-paul-s-netro-1506943906.jpg', 'team': 4, 'vision': 5, 'product': 5, 'profile': 0, 'review': '', 'weight': '3%', 'agree': 0} | 2017-09-29 | Gerard Paul S. Netro | gerard-paul-s-netro | Blockchain Entrepreneur & ICO Expert | https://icobench.com/images/users/gerard-paul-s-netro-1506943906.jpg | 4 | 5 | 5 | 0 |  | 3% | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

Another easier single line approach would be,

```
df = pd.json_normalize(<dictionary to flatten>, record_path = ['ratings'])
df
```

Note: You need pandas 1.x.x to run `pd.json_normalize()`